# Getting "Error Establishing a Database Connection" on localhost in new Mac OSX Lion environment

Tags: database, mysql, localhost

I just got a new Macbook Air and I've been manually migrating my files and code over from my old Macbook (instead of using Migration Assistant, to avoid bringing cruft).

I had several sites running Wordpress locally (on my old Macbook), as well as several sites running just statically with no CMS.

I think I've gotten Apache and MySQL all configured (installed MySQL on the new Mac with Homebrew, and using Sequel Pro to admin it) correctly, but I keep getting the "Error establishing a database connection" for all of my Wordpress sites.

The static sites are running on their local domains just fine, so that's why I think I have Apache and relevant files set up correctly (hosts, httpd.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf all just copied over from the old machine). And, I have the wp-config.php files matched up correctly with the MySQL db's, users and pw's.

So what on earth am I missing that's giving me this error on all my Wordpress installs??

Comment: Are you able to login into mysql from command line with the user name and password?

Comment: Haven't tried, I use Sequel Pro to interface with my databases.

Comment: The most useful way to debug this error is to open wp-config.php and add the following line: define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was twofold:

1) Although I had updated the mysql default socket location from `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` to `/tmp/mysql.sock`, once in `php.ini`, there were apparently two statements for this in the file (not sure why) and the second was still overwriting the first. So I just changed the second to the `/tmp/mysql.sock` value as well.

2) For whatever reason, the user I had setup for Wordpress and password were not being given access to the database. So in `wp-config.php` I ended up just setting the user to `root` for my local dev purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Never used SequelPro but in phpMyAdmin sometimes when I create the database I forget to select `localhost` from the drop down selection. If you just type it into the text field it doesn't work, you have to select `localhost` from the dropdown.

Ever used XAMPP? I highly recommend it, it's an all in one package.

Comment: No, I haven't used XAMPP. I have MAMP installed on my box but haven't used it yet. May try that. I'll look to see if there's an equivalent for the localhost suggestion in SequelPro. Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly, now I can't even log into Sequel Pro via socket. It's telling me that the socket is not found: http://cl.ly/HYj1

Comment: Okay, the socket error was because I didn't have sqlserver running. Hah! Now that I started it, I can login to Sequel Pro, but still getting the error message.